# How to get around 1000 records limit in Active Directory with T-SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, active-directory, active-directory-group

Code below works perfectly* if I limit the cursor to a few groups but if I let it run against our whole domain I encounter 1000 records limit in AD.  Any ideas on how to get this paging?

*perfectly because it should only return a limited number of records which number below the 1000 record limit.

```
CREATE TABLE #MemberOfGroups
(
    groupName   VARCHAR (400),
    cn          VARCHAR (400),
    displayName VARCHAR (400)
);

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @t AS VARCHAR (100), 
@t2 AS VARCHAR (1000), 
@ot AS VARCHAR (4000), 
@tt AS VARCHAR (4000);

DECLARE gC CURSOR
    FOR SELECT cn,
               distinguishedName
        FROM   OPENQUERY (ADSI, 'SELECT cn, distinguishedName
     FROM ''LDAP://DC=coal,DC=local''
     WHERE objectCategory = ''group''');

OPEN gC;

FETCH NEXT FROM gC INTO @t, @t2;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @ot = '''SELECT cn, displayName
     FROM ''''LDAP://DC=coal,DC=local''''
     WHERE objectCategory = ''''Person'''' AND objectClass = ''''user''''
     AND memberOf=''''' + @t2 + '''''';
        SET @tt = 'select ' + '''' + @t + '''' + ' As GroupName, cn, displayName from openquery(ADSI,' + @ot + ''') order by cn';
        INSERT INTO #MemberOfGroups (groupName, cn, displayName)
        EXECUTE (@tt);
        --print @tt
        FETCH NEXT FROM gC INTO @t, @t2;
    END

CLOSE gC;

DEALLOCATE gC;
```

Answer (score 9):

The SQL Server ADO querying into Active Directory is **very limited** and doesn't offer all the capabilities of a full-blown AD interface.

According to Active Directory MVP [Richard Mueller on his web site](http://www.rlmueller.net/SQLDistributedQuery.htm), this limitation of 1000-1500 objects returned from a search **cannot** be circumvented or fixed in SQL Server AD searches:

> *There are two limitations you should be aware of. First, the OPENQUERY statement does not support multi-valued attributes. You cannot retrieve the values of multi-valued attributes, like memberOf. **Second, the total number of records that can be retrieved is limited to 1500** (1000 in Windows 2000 Active Directory). **Paging is not supported** from an SQL distributed query, so this limitation cannot be overcome, except by modifying the Active Directory server limit for maxPageSize.*

So I'm afraid you won't be able to do this directly from SQL Server - you'll have to find another way to achieve this.

Comment: There are options if you don't care about speed and are willing to be a little hacky.  e.g you could fire off 26 queries for each group grabbing all users beginning with 'a' then 'b' etc and aggregating these into a temp table or similar.  Other methods of partitioning may be more appropriate but this was the easiest to explain.